# Upload multiple files i Varien file uploader

Tags: varien-file-uploader, multiple-file-upload

So I tried to create a customized form action, based on the built in contacts form in Magento.

I managed to send an uploaded file in an attachment email, and save it to a folder. But I would like to upload multiple files.

Form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Leave') ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('a') ?> <b><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Message') ?></b></h2>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="form-list col-sm-6">
            <li>
                <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form-list col-sm-6">
            <li>
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box input-textarea">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3" placeholder="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
<li>
    <label for="attachment"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Attachment') ?></label>
    <div>
        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="2000000" />
        <input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>
</li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);

//]]>
</script>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
 public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }



/**************************************************************/
        $fileName = '';
foreach ($_files as $filename => $fileOpt) {
                if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != '') {
                    try {
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $fileName       = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('attachment');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc', 'docx','pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'zip')); //add more file types you want to allow
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'contacts';
                        if(!is_dir($path)){
                            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                        }
                        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            /**************************************************************/

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */

     /**************************************************************/
         //sending file as attachment
                $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'contacts' . DS . $fileName;
                if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                    $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                    $attachment   = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                    $attachment->filename = $fileName;
                }
                /**************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement and able to achieve using following code.

```
public function postAction()
   {
       $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
        $postObject = new Varien_Object();
        $postObject->setData($post);
        $error = false;
        if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
            $error = true;
        }
        /**************************************************************/
       $photos = array();
        foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key => $image) {

        if (empty($image)) {
            continue;
        }

        $fileName = '';

        if (isset($_FILES['photo']['name'][$key]) && $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key] != '') {

        try {

        $fileName = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
        $fileExt = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));

        $fileNamewoe = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
        $fileName = preg_replace('/\s+', '', $fileNamewoe) . time() . $key . '.' . $fileExt;
        if(!in_array($fileExt,array('jpg','jpeg', 'png','gif'))){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('rga')->__('Only jpg, jpeg, png and gif file types are allowed.'));
            session_write_close();
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
        array_push($photos, $fileName);
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
        array(
            'name' => $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key],
            'type' => $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error' => $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key],
            'size' => $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key]
                )
        );
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg', 'png','gif'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'rga';
        if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = true;
        }
        }
        }
        /**************************************************************/
        if ($error) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('rga')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            session_write_close();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
        /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
        /**************************************************************/
        //sending file as attachment

        foreach($photos as $pic) {
            $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . 'rga' . DS . $pic;
            if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);
                $attachment = $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                $attachment->filename = $pic;
            }
        }
        /**************************************************************/
        $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
        ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
        ->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
        null,
        array('data' => $postObject)
        );

        if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('rga')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            session_write_close();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('rga')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
        session_write_close();
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('rga')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
        session_write_close();       
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
        }
        } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
   }
```

You can go through it and modify it according to your requirement.
I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I solved it with this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609709/upload-multiple-files-with-varien-file-uploader - But I will try to implement your solution to keep images in email attachment

Comment: Where to add this code and how it will be execute?